# Elastic Date Format

Tags: elasticsearch

I have specified the mapping info in the template as below:

```
    "createdDate": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis||EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z YYYY||dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
            },
"expirationDate": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis||EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z YYYY||dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
            }
```

And when i tried to insert a Doc into the index i am getting the following error.

```
PUT my_index/MyDocType/5c7ab034-5de3-4401-8b46-7f8158618b68
{
  "uuid": "5c7ab034-5de3-4401-8b46-7f8158618b68",
  "createdDate": "15 Apr 2019 14:10:10 EDT",
  "expirationDate": "10 Oct 2019 00:00:00 EDT"

}
```

And here is the Error i am getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse [createdDate]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse [createdDate]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Invalid format: \"15 Apr 2019 14:10:10 EDT\" is malformed at \" Apr 2019 14:10:10 EDT\""
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I can parse the String Values using following with out any issues. Not sure why Elastic is complaining while parsing the Month part of the Date String !!

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [link](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html), below is what `z` and `Z` means

```
z time zone                    text               Pacific Standard Time; PST
Z time zone offset/id          zone               -0800; -08:00; America/Los_Angeles
```

It appears that your format is not valid Joda [DateTimeFormat](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

Adding the correct format `dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z` to your mapping, as mentioned below, should solve your issue.

```
{  
   "createdDate":{  
      "type":"date",
      "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis||EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z YYYY||dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz||dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
   }
}
```

Hope it helps!